# Foreignsecurityprincipal remove from group

Tags: c#, active-directory

How to remove a user (foreign security principal) from Active Directory group?
I tried using:

```
group.Properties["member"].Remove(memberEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"]);
```

and:

```
group.Properties["member"].Remove(foreignSid);
```

where foreignSid is, for example:

```
<SID=1-4234324-xxx-xxx>
```

None of the above works.

Answer (score 0):

Your first try was almost correct. It's just:

```
group.Properties["member"].Remove("distinguishedName");
```

Don't forget to use `group.CommitChanges();` to invoke the changes made to the group.

Btw. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180905(v=vs.90).aspx) is amazing on basic AD controls with .NET

If you want to add/remove group members by SID you need to query your AD users for the SID first and then take the DN of the found element.